# One plugin for drupal 6 and 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I wrote drupal plugin, that compatible with drupal6 and drupal7. Is there any way to share it as one plugin?

in *.info file there is **core = 7.x** or **core = 6.x**. May be I can set smth like **core = 6.x, 7.x**?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that.

You'll have to duplicate the module files with different `.info` file.